# Second foreign_key to speed up query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Say you creating an imdb type site for TV Shows.  You have a `Show` with many attached `episodes` and a bunch of `people`

Right now I link `people` to `episodes` though a `contribution` table - but if I want to make a list of all the **shows** they are on, I have to go through episodes.

Since this query takes a long time I was thinking about adding `show_id` to the `contributions` table.  Is this common practice to increase performance or is there another way I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since this query takes a long time

Have you run a SQL explain plan to show why this is the case?  What is the actual SQL query that is being run, and are you doing things like ordering or running subqueries within it?

If I understand your structure it is something like this:

```
|people| n---1 |contribution| 1---n |episodes| n---1 |shows|
```

A sql select of the sort:

```
select distinct s.name 
from   shows s,
       episodes e,
       contribution c
where  c.people_id = <id>
and    c.episode_id = e.id
and    e.show_id = s.id
```

should really not have performance issues unless there are no indexes on the tables or the tables are massive.

Comment: This is the fastest method I've been able to come up with:  

s_ids = Episode.joins(:contributions)
  .where("contributions.role_name = 'guest'")
  .where("contributions.contributable_type = 'Episode'")
  .where('contributions.person_id IN (?)', self.id)
  .distinct
  .pluck('episodes.show_id')
  
shows = Show.where(id: s_ids)
  .order('score DESC NULLS LAST')

Comment: Are your tables indexed?  If so, are the correct columns indexed?  Have you captured the SQL generated by your AR queries above and actually run it in a MYSQL console with an EXPLAIN to see the output?

Comment: First query: SELECT DISTINCT episodes.show_id FROM "episodes" INNER JOIN "contributions" ON "contributions"."contributable_id" = "episodes"."id" AND "contributions"."contributable_type" = $1 WHERE (contributions.role_name = 'guest') AND (contributions.contributable_type = 'Episode') AND (contributions.person_id IN (159))  [["contributable_type", "Episode"]]

Comment: Second query: SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows" WHERE "shows"."id" IN (0..10000) AND (pic_file_name IS NOT NULL)  ORDER BY score DESC NULLS LAST

Comment: contribution has index on 'contributable_type' (show or episode) and 'contributable_id' and 'person_id', episodes have index on show_id

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `where id in ( ... )` to select all shows a specific person appeared in

```
Shows.where(id: Contribution.select("show_id")
    .join(:episodes)
    .where(person_id: personId)
    .group("episodes.show_id"))
```

You may also want to try `exists`

```
Shows.where("EXISTS(SELECT 1 from contributions c 
  join episodes e on e.id = c.episode_id
  where c.person_id = ? and e.show_id = shows.id)")
```